# Cómo ordenar mi código Angular

Tags: visual-studio

Amigos, tengo un problema un poco molesto al escribir código en archivos `.js`, al momento de presionar `Enter` el código subyacente se desordena completamente y la legibilidad se pierde totalmente lo que me causa confusiones y perdidas de tiempo.

Les dejo un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno de ustedes sabe como arreglar de manera rápida esto?
Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio e ignoro si hay alguna extensión de ordenamiento o parecido.

Toda sugerencia se agradece.

Comment: Has probado CTRL+K y despues CTRL+D?

Comment: Amigo, a usted deberían hacerle una estatua :D . Todos los días se aprende algo. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: De nada hombre :) Creo que lo añadiré como respuesta por si alguien no conoce esa combinación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que Visual Studio realice una Auto-indentación del código, puede utilizarse la combinación de teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> seguidas de <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Toda la información de combinaciones de teclado están aqui [Métodos abreviados de teclado predeterminados de Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/da5kh0wa.aspx). Ésta concretamente se encuentra bajo el epígrafe `Edit.FormatDocument`